# AngularJS - sanitize apostrophe

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used "angular-sanitize.js" to sanitize the characters, but I'm still getting `&#039;` in my text.

How do I display this correctly in AngularJS?

Comment: Please give some more details and maybe a little bit of sample code (aim for the smallest code you can manage that still shows the problem)